# DirectoryNotFoundException for an existing file path (continued)

Tags: unity

[DirectoryNotFoundException for an existing file path on Unity startup](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168959/directorynotfoundexception-for-an-existing-file-path-on-unity-startup)

I did what TehMightyPotato suggested (see the link above), and managed to solve the issue. However, the next day when i opened up the same project, Unity was unable to find the .asmdef files. It seems like rearranging the .asmdef files deleted them as well.

What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Try explaining exactly the steps you took, so we understand your interpretation of the answer you've linked.

Comment: Did you accidentally open the project at its old location instead of the copy you made at a new location with a shorter path?

Comment: Problem solved. I misunderstood what TehMightyPotato suggested. I moved the .asmdef file instead of the whole project file, that's why Unity couldn't find the .asmdef files when i tried opening the next day. I also had to re-import the project file into Unity hub so that Unity opens the file from the new location. Thank you Kevin and Gregory for the help!

Comment: Want to share your solution as an Answer below?